# Drupal: custom block doesn't appear

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am new at Drupal 7 and I'm creating a Block by code, following this [tutorial](http://redcrackle.com/blog/how-create-block-drupal-7).

So I create a new module folder at **drupal/sites/all/modules** and created two files:

**block_square_menu.info:** it has the info of the module:

```
name = Block Square Menu
description = Module that create a Block for Square menu, menu shown only in home page
core = 7.x
package = custom
```

**block_square_menu.module:** it contains the PHP code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function block_square_block_info() {
    $blocks = array();
    $blocks['block_square'] = array(
        'info' => t('Block Square'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
    );

    return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function block_square_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'block_square':
            $block['subject'] = t('block Title');
            $block['content'] = t('Hello World!');
            break;
    }
    return $block;
}
```

After save the files, I go to **Admin/Modules**, I activate the new module and save the configuration. Now I go to **Structure/Blocks** and it should list my new Block, but it doesn't do.

I have followed all the tutorial steps and I cleaned Drupal cache, but I'm still having the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the problem was the name of the functions. So the names started with "block_square"  which it have the word "block" and it causes some trouble so I changed the all the names with menu_square.

So the functions are now:

- menu_square_block_info()
- menu_square_block_view($delta = '')

And the files are:

- menu_square.info
- menu_square.module

The code of the files are:

info:

```
name = Menu Square
description = Module that create a Block for Square menu, menu shown only in home page
core = 7.x
package = custom
```

module:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function menu_square_block_info() {
    $blocks['menu_square'] = array(
        'info' => t('Block Square'),
        //'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
    );

    return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function menu_square_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'menu_square':
            $block['subject'] = t('block Title');
            $block['content'] = t('Hello World!');
            break;
    }
    return $block;
}
```

Comment: Okay then i updated my answer i hope it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

First solve your mistake: change the function name where you implemented hook_block_view(), you need to change it as **function blocks_square_block_view()**

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */

```
function blocks_square_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();
     ......
```

After also if not solve then remove '**cache**' attribute from hook_block_info() it is optional.

Then follow 2 steps if you missed.

1) Clear all cache **(/admin/config/development/performance)**.

2) Enable your custom module **(/admin/modules)**.

After trying again, your block should appear in **(/admin/structure/block)**.

Comment: I have changed the name function as you say, and I have removed the cache attribute, but it doesn't work